# Can't see GUI components in applet?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, applet

For some reason  my GUI components are not displaying inside of my applet. I set up a separate class where I create all of my GUI components and add them to a panel I created. After that I add that object with the created panels to the applet but for some reason it is not showing up on my applet. I made sure to set the visibility on my applet to true after adding the object that held my components but that didn't help either.

```
public class CreatePannel extends JPanel{

JPanel panel=new JPanel();

public CreatePanel()  {//This is my constructor for the object that I created to create my components and add them to my panel called leftPanel that I set as an instance variable at the start of this class.  
  JButton button=new JButton();
  panel.add(button);
  }
}

 public class GUI extends JApplet{

  public void init() {// In a separate class that extends Applet
   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   CreatePanel test=new CreatePanel();
   add(test);//TRYING TO ADD GUI COMPONENTS TO MY APPLET
   setVisible(true); 
   }

 }
```

Comment: Please post a valid [mcve]. Let's see what you're really doing.

Comment: Also, if this is a school assignment where you're required to use applets, well so be it, but please understand that applets are considered "dead" technology as most browsers do not fully support them, and even Oracle, the force behind Java, will no longer be supporting them. Please see [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). Other options include use of HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript and JavaFX/WebView.

Comment: OK, well this means that you're stuck with a teacher that teaches dead technologies, and I truly feel for you. But again, if you need our help in figuring out what's wrong, we're going to need more code, not all of it, but enough to allow us to run the code and experience the problem, a [mcve]. Please read the link.

Comment: Ok Added everything that I have. I thought my problem was that I used the setVisible(true) before adding my components but that dosent seem to be the case here.

Comment: Your `CreatePannel` doesn't extend JPanel or any other Swing JComponent -- how can you even add it to a JApplet's contentPane?

Comment: My CreatePannel does extend JPanel?

Comment: ??? Look at your code: `public class CreatePannel{` is not the same as `public class CreatePannel extends JPanel {`. Do you note a difference?

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrong, I was accidentally adding it to the constructor instead of the class name.

Comment: Post your *real* code, not typed code. You then don't appear to be adding anything to CreatePanel instance, so of course nothing will show.

Comment: This is exactly what I have in my IDE. In regards to your comment, I am adding a button to my panel on my CreatePanel object so I am adding stuff to my CreatePanel instance.

Comment: ?? I don't see `.add(...);` or `this.add(...);` anywhere. And that can't be  your code, as it won't compile. You've got an unclosed constructor, two classes together, mismatched braces,... sorry but it's a mess. If you have real questions or problems, please show *real* code, not kind-of sort-of code. It would help us and help you both.

Comment: You add the button to the panel object, but what do you add panel to? I see you adding it to nothing.

Comment: I just copied and paste everything from my IDE. I am adding the pannel with the button to the applet. Its under the add(test) line. The line with the comments in caps.

Comment: No, that doesn't add the panel; that adds the CreatePannel object, an objec that does not display the panel. You need `add(panel);` in your CreatePannel constructor.

Answer (score -2):

You never add your components to the GUI. This constructor:

```
public CreatePanel()  {
    JButton button=new JButton();
    panel.add(button);
}
```

creates a JButton and adds it to the panel JPanel but then does nothing with these guys as they're never added to the containing JPanel class. You need more, specifically:

```
public CreatePanel()  {
    JButton button=new JButton();
    panel.add(button);
    this.add(panel);  // the "this" is not actually needed but there for emphasis
}
```

This code now adds the panel JPanel to the containing CreatePannel object which then is eventually added to the JApplet.